# how to prevent an overlapped segments in geom_segment

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, data-visualization, geom-segment

I'm trying to map different ranges (lines) into different regions in the plot (see below) using `geom_segment` but some of the ranges overlap and can't be shown at all.
This is a minimal example for a dataframes:

```
start = c(1, 5,8, 14)
end =c(3, 6,12, 16)
regions = c(1,2,3, 4)

regions = data_frame(regions, start, end)

from = c(1,2, 5.5, 13.5)
to = c(3,2.5,6, 15)

lines = data_frame(from, to)
```

I plotted the regions with `geom_rect` and then plot the ranges (lines) with `geom_segment`.
This is the plot:

```
plot_splice <- ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,16)) +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.6,
             size = 20,
             alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(
    data = regions,
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = start,
      xmax = end,
      ymin = 1.5,
      ymax = 1.8,
    )) +
  geom_segment(
    data = lines,
    x = (lines$from),
    xend = (lines$to),
    y = 1.48,
    yend = 1.48,
    colour = "red",
    size = 3
    ) +
  ylim(1.0, 2.2) + 
  xlab("") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The first plot is the one generated with the code whereas the second one is the desired plot.

[image]

As you can see, the second line overlaps with the first one, so you can't see the second line at all.

How can I change the code to produce the second plot?

I'm trying to use `ifelse` statement but not sure what is `test` argument should be:
I want it to check for each range (line) if it is overlapped with any previous range (line) to change the `y` position by around `.05`, so it doesn't overlap.

```
lines <- lines %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(from))

new_y$lines = ifelse(from[1] < to[0], 1.48, 1.3)

geom_segment(
    data = lines,
    x = (lines$from),
    xend = (lines$to),
    y = new_y,
    yend = new_y,
    colour = "red",
    size = 3
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `geom_segment` call isn't using any aesthetic mapping, which is how you normally get ggplot elements to change position based on a particular variable (or set of variables).

The stacking of the `geom_segment` based on the number of overlapping regions is best calculated ahead of the call to ggplot. This allows you to pass the x and y values into an aesthetic mapping:

```r
# First ensure that the data frame is ordered by the start time
lines <- lines[order(lines$from),]

# Now iterate through each row, calculating how many previous rows have
# earlier starts but haven't yet finished when the current row starts.
# Multiply this number by a small negative offset and add the 1.48 baseline value
lines$offset <- 1.48 - 0.03 * sapply(seq(nrow(lines)), function(i) {
   with(lines[seq(i),], length(which(from < from[i] & to > from[i])))
   })
```

Now do the same plot but using aesthetic mapping inside `geom_segment`:

```r
 ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,16), name = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 2.2), name = "") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.6,
             size = 20,
             alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(
    data = regions,
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = start,
      xmax = end,
      ymin = 1.5,
      ymax = 1.8,
    )) +
  geom_segment(
    data = lines,
    mapping = aes(
      x = from, 
      xend = to, 
      y = offset, 
      yend = offset),
    colour = "red",
    size = 3
    ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]